Testing Microsoft Teams Apps in CI
We have a Microsoft Teams tab app which is essentially a react app running inside Microsoft Teams. We use Playwright for automated end-to-end testing of our application (in a browser context) however there are many instances where the application will behave differently when embedded in Microsoft Teams. Is there any way to run automated testing of our application when running inside Microsoft Teams that will also run in our CI?
From my research it looks like Teams uses webView2 which Playwright might be able to hook into, but I was wondering if there is a more generic option for testing GUI apps like Microsoft Teams within a CI pipeline.
